# How to read xml document in MVC core (1.0.0)?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm new to web programming and decided to switch from .net 4.5 to .net core.

My project has a static xml document in the following location:

> wwwroot/Countries/en-GB.xml

How would one go about reading the xml file at the specified path? Eventually I will convert the data to a SelectList.

In .net 4.5 I used DataSet's and HttpConext...MapPath to read the xml document which no longer works in core mvc.

Any advice is greatly welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all don't put your data source into `wwwroot` folder, because it is served publicly. Take a look at [official docs](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/intro.html#web-root):

> The web root of your app is the directory in your project for public,
>   static resources like css, js, and image files. The static files
>   middleware will only serve files from the web root directory (and
>   sub-directories) by default.

So move `Countries` folder in your project's root folder.

To read xml data, you can use `XmlSerializer`. I will try to show how to read xml file:

First i assume you have xml content like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Container>
  <Countries>
    <Country>
      <Code>Code1</Code>
      <Title>Title1</Title>
    </Country>

    <Country>
      <Code>Code2</Code>
      <Title>Title2</Title>
    </Country>
  </Countries>
</Container>
```

First describe types

```
public class Country
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
public class Container
{
    public Country[] Countries { get; set; }
}
```

After that create a service for xml deserialization:

```
public interface ICountryService
{
    Country[] GetCountries();
}
public class CountryService : ICountryService
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _env;
    public CountryService(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }
    public Country[] GetCountries()
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Container));
        FileStream myFileStream = new FileStream(_env.ContentRootPath + "\\Countries\\en-GB.xml", FileMode.Open);
        return ((Container)ser.Deserialize(myFileStream)).Countries;
    }
}
```

Then register service in `ConfigureServices` method:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ...
        services.AddSingleton<ICountryService, CountryService>();
    }
```

Finally inject and use it anywhere(such as in a controller)

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    public SomeController(ICountryService countryService)
    {
         // use it
    }
}
```

Comment: Really great and detailed answer. Your solution works perfect. It took me a few attempts to understand why I was getting error, but it was because of my xml data structures, but now it's clear to me. I  very much appreciate your time to provide a comprehensive answer.

Comment: This is a good answer if you aren't using attributes from an earlier version of asp.net. I used attributes to map attributes to data members. How do I accomplish this in core?