# How to parse nodes with mixed repeating and non-repeating child nodes?

Tags: c#, .net-core, xmlserializer

Let's start by disposing of any notion that this might be a duplicate of [How to read xml document in MVC core (1.0.0)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39552474/how-to-read-xml-document-in-mvc-core-1-0-0) which considers only this structure, trivially expressible as `things: thing[]`.

```
<things>
  <thing>..</thing>
  <thing>..</thing>
  <thing>..</thing>
  …
</things>
```

This question is about how to express the following as classes.

```
<things>
  <a>..</a>
  <b>..</b>
  <c>..</c>
  <d>..</d>
  <d>..</d>
  <d>..</d>
  …
</things>
```

This is absolutely *not* an array. It *is* arguably a dictionary but we are expressly forbidden from using `IDictionary<T1,T2>` with `XmlSerializer`.

Normally I would start with the classes and let XmlSerializer tell me the XML format, but this XML is defined by a system out of my control.

Compounding the problem is the fact that string is a sealed class, so you can't inherit from it, making it impossible to alias it for the purpose of naming the fields.

How do I deserialise a node with mixed repeating and non-repeating child nodes?

Comment: And what result would you like to get in C#? Arrays a[], b[], c[], etc or dictionary or something else?

Comment: Anything, @AlexanderPetrov, so long as I can parse the XML. I don't mind writing my code around the data structure.

Comment: Should we get the same xml when serializing? Or serialization is not important?

Comment: I'm not serialising. I'm consuming the output of a legacy system to print labels. When I replace that part of the greater system I'll probably use JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you find it, the answer is embarrassingly simple: you apply the `XmlElement` attribute to the array member. Further details at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/controlling-xml-serialization-using-attributes#serializing-an-array-as-a-sequence-of-elements

```
public class thing {
  public string a { get; set; }
  public string b { get; set; }
  public string c { get; set; }
  [XmlElement]
  public string[] d { get; set; }
}
```

We can then parse zero or more occurrences of `d` as direct children without a collection node to own and type them, into an array property on our `thing` object.

To clarify the effect of the attribute, the value of the property `thing.d` is a *collection* in which the elements are anonymous and have type string. Serialisation exactly reflects this, giving you a collection node "d" with child nodes that get their names from their type:

```
<things>
  <a>..</a>
  <b>..</b>
  <c>..</c>
  <d>
    <string>..</string>
    <string>..</string>
    …
  </d>
</things>
```

However, this is not what we are trying to parse. The `[XmlElement]` attribute prevents the property from being treated as a collection, and if it isn't a collection the only *other* way it can map to XML is as a repeating element.

Answer (score 1):

For me it looks like an array of objects of different types which possibly inherit same base class. I would do something like this:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(A))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(B))]
...
public class BaseClass {}

[XmlRoot("a")]
public class A : BaseClass { }

[XmlRoot("b")]
public class B : BaseClass { }
...

public class Things
{
   [XmlElement("things")]
   public BaseClass[] Items { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I seriously thought about marking this as the accepted answer. I found the answer for myself but Kirill posted while I was in the process of writing up my result. I finally chose to mark my own answer as correct because it is both simpler and more explanatory. Kirill's answer doesn't say _why_ you need `[XmlElement]` on `d`, nor does it explain why you _don't_ need it on the non-repeating elements. Nevertheless, I appreciate his time and effort - thank you, Kirill.